# Strange css or javascript bug in iOs

Tags: javascript, css, ios, iphone, vue.js

I can't find the solution, if you open this section of my website on your mobile with Safari or Chrome INSIDE iOs:
https://wanapix.co.uk/login

You will find the screen badly designed (it doesn't matter if you open it with Safari or Chrome inside iOs, it's an iOs-only problem):
[image]

If you use Android you will see that it looks perfect. And in fact, Chrome Dev Tools shows it correctly:

[image]

What could iOs be doing to affect css or javascript in this way? Using Safari debug I can't find anything.

Comment: Any possibility that you enabled website view in your iOS device?

Comment: I do not have desktop view enabled.

Comment: I just realized that it is happening when switching from desktop view to mobile view in Chrome Dev Tools. When you reload the page in mobile view page loads well. Probably an implementation problem in your code

Comment: Yes, but that's because I give a different layout on mobile and desktop with PHP conditionals.

Comment: @AntonioMorales, it seems that vue-tabs isn't initialized in ios/safari mobile browser.  Please check your js module loading. Did you use conditional loading of js modules based on ios/android platform?